# LaunchScreen not working for different devices

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

### Explanation

I'm trying to make my `LaunchScreen.storyboard` work for every device, from iPhone 4 to iPad Pro. This way, I created 3 resolutions images:

launchScreen@3x = 1366x1024 (iPad Pro/maximum size)
launchScreen@2x = 911x683 (1366*2/3 x 1024*2/3)
launchScreen = 455x341 (1366*1/3 x 1024*1/3)

but when I add them to the project and add missing constraints, they won't work proberly, as you can see below.

[image]

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I've searched in many places, but couldn't find anything. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: Can you share any demo project?

Comment: yes, of course. Right [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8t84zi8zsvdj6r8/AAD6yH1OgSPPRBRdZouGy65Ua?dl=0).

Comment: So you always want that image in center?

Comment: yes, my ideia is to be centered in every device

Comment: Something like this: https://i.gyazo.com/24a31f0aa8e3b1b0c91a103bea2e225a.png?

Comment: This solved the position, but the size is still different. I was thinking in a full screen launchscreen for every device

Comment: Check this: https://i.gyazo.com/9f916ae510752eebdc7062e21de7fbdb.png

Comment: Ok I am posting answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if all remove all constraint from your image view.

After that set your `imageView` content mode to `Scale To Fill`.

Then give constraint to your `imageView` like this:

[image]

And your result will be:

[image]

And [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=49988603518275558228) is your sample code for more info.

Comment: Thank youuu!! It worked perfectly!! Just for a information matter (and, if possible, project improvement): is there any way to keep the rectangle a rectangle? For example, it "turned" into a square in when running in iPads (and almost a square in iPhone 4/4s).

Comment: Dont include both in one image. Make it separate and give constraint.

Comment: Hi! Sorry to bother you, but I just created the separate images and it kept "turning" into a square (as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/bkNTSXj.png)). I set the same constraints and the scale mode to `Scale to Fill`.

Comment: You can download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xhyevmobigdhntk/AABW3StOV5-M2NsNMrjVI018a?dl=0) =)